# jQuery slideshow with images pulled from rails doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails-3, slideshow

I am trying to implement a slideshow in Rails 3.2, but without luck.
I tried to follow this tutorial [http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery/demo/jquery_demo_image_swap_gallery.htm](http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery/demo/jquery_demo_image_swap_gallery.htm/), but since I am new to Rails and jQuery I am completely lost on how to apply the commands to call the images from the database.

Therefore I really appreciate if you guys can help me out to get it sortet.

So far all images (one main image on top and below 4 small ones (the main one + 3 other)) are called from the database and displayed correctly on the webpage, but I would like to apply a slide-show to it to make it look nicer. By hovering over the smaller images below they shall be displayed as the main picture on top.

That's the code I have:

**app/views/homes/show.html.erb**

```
<div class="homepics"> 
    <div class="homemainpic">
    <%= image_tag "/"+@home.images[0].image_path, :size => "925x600" %>
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% @home.images.each {|image| %>
    <li><%= image_tag "/"+image.image_path, :size => "220x150" %></li>
    <% } %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**app/assets/javascripts**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".homemainpic li image_tag").hover(function() {
        $('image_tag').attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('image_tag "/"+image.image_path'));
    });

    var imgSwap = [];
        $(".homemainpic li image_tag").each(function() {
            imgURL = this.src.replace('image_tag "/"+image.image_path');
            imgSwap.push(imgURL);
    });

    $(imgSwap).preload();
});

    $.fn.preload = function() {
        this.each(function() {
            $('image_tag "/"+@home.images[0].image_path') [0].src = this;
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".homepics ul img").on('mouseover', function () {
    $('.homemainpic img').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ethagnawl/fwFym/)

Comment: Thanks @ethagnawl. Do you mean only to replace the first two lines of the code and to leave the rest? 
Or to replace all `.homemainpic li image_tag` with `.homepics ul img` and all current `image_tag`with `.homemeinpic img`?

Comment: YOU ARE A HERO!!! I only replaced the first two lines and it works like a charme. Many thanks for that.

Comment: Sorry, Ron, but I didn't have a chance to respond to your question today. I'm glad you were able to sort things out. :)

Comment: No problem at all. I didn't know Fiddle and therefore didn't click on it the first time, but it is pretty cool and explained what I needed. Thanks again!!!
I am still struggeling to get the logic of jQuery and JavaScript. :-/